# engineio - Python3.7 async SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-socketio

I'm very much a novice at all of this. Trying to troubleshoot another application for raspberry pi, keep running into this issue. I've read that async is now a reserved word for Python 3.7, cant change the script in server.py. There is probably an easy solution, but I'm too novice to see it. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from modules import socketio, app, cbpi
  File "/home/pi/craftbeerpi3/modules/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socketio import socketio_manage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/socketio/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .middleware import Middleware
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/socketio/middleware.py", line 1, in <module>
    import engineio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/engineio/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .server import Server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/engineio/server.py", line 89
    self.async = None
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you please add a sample of your code aswell as your vesrion of python you are running

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of the python-socketio and python-engineio packages. Upgrade to a more recent release to resolve this problem.